# findbugsMain task in gradle fails

Tags: gradle, findbugs, build.gradle

I'm trying to run the findbugsMain task in Gradle 1.10 (or more specific "gradlew check") but the only thing I get is an error like

```
building findbugsMain 33% > ...
:findbugsMain FAILED
```

It seems to download the required jars though:

```
...
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.1/jaxen-1.1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.3/asm-3.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.3/asm-tree-3.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.3/asm-commons-3.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.6.2/xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xom/xom/1.0/xom-1.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xmlParserAPIs/2.6.2/xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xalan/xalan/2.6.0/xalan-2.6.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/2.6.1/icu4j-2.6.1.jar
:findbugsMain FAILED
```

I ran the task using --stacktravce again and this is what I got:
[Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/JsrCqn7Y)
My build.gradle is also on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JH6UE7sp)

I'm relatively new to build management tools in general and gradle in particular, so it might be my fault (e.g. buildscript has an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems FindBugs up to version 2.0.3 has problems with some Java 8 classfiles. These 
problems will be addressed in the next major version of FindBugs. Until then you have to use Java 7.

So, the short version is, that I changed the language level to 1.7 and everything runs just fine now.

Thanks @peter for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the stack trace, some internal error occurs. This could be due to an incompatibility between the version of the ASM library used by Gradle, and the version expected by FindBugs. Would you mind to file an issue over at http://forums.gradle.org, ideally including a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Sure. Anything that'll help to get that fixed.